# Elasticsearch filter to obtain the last document for each value of given field

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider the following set of documents :

```
{transaction: "A", date: "1999-10-27" }
{transaction: "B", date: "1999-10-26" }
{transaction: "C", date: "1999-10-26" }
{transaction: "A", date: "1999-10-27" }
{transaction: "A", date: "1999-12-25" }
{transaction: "B", date: "2000-10-25" }
```

I'm trying to add a filter that would only select the last document for each `transaction`, based of the value of the field `date` and obtain the following documents :

```
{transaction: "C", date: "1999-10-26" }
{transaction: "A", date: "1999-12-25" }
{transaction: "B", date: "2000-10-25" }
```

Also, a term aggregation wouldn't work because I also need to make a histogram aggregation (by year) on the resulting documents

```
{
    1999: 2
}, {
    2000: 1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve what you need.

A. Using the [collapse feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html)

```
GET test/_search
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "transaction",
    "inner_hits": [
      {
        "name": "latest",      
        "size": 1,
        "sort": [
          {
            "date": {
              "order": "desc"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

B. Using a `terms` aggregation on the `transaction` field + a `top_hits` sorted on `date` for the latest transaction

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "transactions": {
      "terms": { 
        "field": "transaction" 
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                 "date": { 
                    "order": "desc"
                 }
              }
            ]                   
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using the above query, it is then trivial to figure out a date histogram in your application logic.

**UPDATE:**

If you really want ES to build that date histogram for you, you can achieve this by leveraging the [`scripted_metric` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) and building the aggregation logic yourself. Note that this solution uses scripting and it might impair the performance of your cluster depending on the volume of your data.

```
POST test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "years": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.latest = [:]",
        "map_script": """
          // 1. record the latest year for each transaction
          def key = doc['transaction.keyword'].value;
          if (!state.latest.containsKey(key)) {
            state.latest[key] = 0;
          }
          def year = doc['date'].value.getYear();
          if (state.latest[key] < year) {
            state.latest[key] = year;
          }
        """,
        "combine_script": """
          return state.latest
        """,
        "reduce_script": """
          // 2. count how many documents per "latest" year
          def years = [:];
          states.stream().forEach(shardState -> {
            shardState.keySet().stream().forEach(transaction -> {
              def year = shardState[transaction].toString();
              if (!years.containsKey(year)) {
                years[year] = 0;
              }
              years[year]++;
            });
          });
          return years;
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For instance, the above aggregation query would work and return the following, which is pretty much what you expect:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "years" : {
      "value" : {
        "2000" : 1,
        "1999" : 2
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I've tried both solutions :  It seems that the collapse "does not affect aggregations" and the  "top_hits" aggregation "cannot accept sub-aggregations". These solutions can filter documents as intended but, in both case, I'm not able to make aggregations on the filtered documents.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but that wasn't specified in your initial question. Please explain your use case in more details. Help us help you !!

Comment: Maybe I wasn't being clear but, that's what I meant by "Also, a term aggregation wouldn't work because I also need to make a histogram aggregation (by year) on the resulting documents"

Comment: Ok, I understand now... So in the above example, you need a date histogram that returns something like: 1999: 2 docs, 2000: 1 doc ?

Comment: Yes, exactly : a date histogram on the remaining documents

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: works fine, thanks